# Scripting in linux

Tags: python, linux

Why `java -version` gives empty string when executing in `subprocess.Popen`. Is there any alternative to get the exact text given by `java -version` command in **Linux**?

```
version = ["java","-version"]

temp1 = subprocess.Popen(version, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
ver = str(temp1.communicate())
print ver
```

Comment: `java -version` outputs to `stderr` not `stdout`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are getting some error so capture the stderr from the process.

```
version = ["java","-version"]
temp1=subprocess.Popen(version, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
output, error = temp1.communicate()
```

Then try to print the error.